# How can I fetch the value from DX:AX/EDX:EAX?

Tags: linux, assembly

I ran a glimpse on the documentation about multiplying values with respect to their sizes. The one for bytes is rather easy so there is no need for me to confuse myself over it. The thing that confuses me is about fetching the product if the operands are word/double word.

For example:

```
    ;code for scanning values here
    ;code for converting them to numbers

    mov ax, word[num] ;suppose num is a word-type value

    mov bx, 45

    mul bx

    mov num, ??? ;??? represents the register where should I fetch the product from
```

I know that there might have been a similar question to this, but I really needed an in-depth explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`mul` instruction gives 32-bit result for 16-bit operands. `ax` holds the lower `word` of the result, and `dx` holds the upper `word`. So, you need a `dword` variable to store the result:

```
result dd 0

. . .
mul bx
mov [result], ax
mov [result + 2], dx
```

However, if you know that your numbers are always small enough, so that resut will not to exceed 65535, then you can omit higher part (`dx`) as it will always be 0, and use 16-bit variable to store the result